# 2 or more Back buttons are exist in Windows 8 Metro apps?

Tags: html, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs

Hi I have a metro application in which am trying to use 3 buttons in my page,First one is default back-button and One is for Submit button and another one is Cancel button.When I click on cancel button page needs to redirect to before page means it has to work like Metro back-button default functionality.What should I do for this Cancel button,Can anyone help me.

Thank you.

Comment: so you want two buttons that do the same thing? Cancel and default back-button? You can use Frame.GoBack, Frame.GoForward, to navigate the back stack if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: He's using WinJS, so Frame isn't applicable.

Comment: I do agree with what Jim may have been implying. If you have a back button, I would get rid of the cancel button.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you've started your app from the Navigation App project template because it gives you the navigation framework. If you didn't and you are well along in your app and need to add navigation, you can do so by following my blog post [here](http://codefoster.com/Page-Navigation-in-Windows-8-JavaScript-Apps).

Then, all you need to do is write some JavaScript for that Cancel button and use WinJS.Navigation.back()

In your ready function, you could use something like...

```
element.querySelector("#myCancelButton").onclick = function(e) {
    WinJS.Navigation.back();
}
```

Hope that helps.